# What exactly "inside the unit disk" mean?

Tags: complex-analysis

I read the question in [Show that the zeros of $\sum_{k=1}^n kz^{k-1}$ are inside the unit disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286810/show-that-the-zeros-of-sum-k-1n-kzk-1-are-inside-the-unit-disc) regarding zeros of polynomial $P(z)$ and I ran into confusion. In the problem in this link, it is required to show that zeroes lie "inside" the unit disk. And according to wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk seems like it means open disk: "Without further specifications, the term unit disk is used for the open unit disk about the origin" but in previous question it seems to treat it as closed disk. Which is true? Though I'm not sure, I have instincts that some of zeroes can lie on the boundary so closed disk is more appropriate but it contradicts wikipedia, so I'm asking for some advice here.

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong here. I think it depends on context at a minimum. In any case, for the question, the roots are not on the boundary.

Comment: But in the book to which the Exercise refer to *open disc* is defined at page 13 (and it is open).

Comment: Although outside the topic of complex analysis, in [geometric topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_topology) the convention is that "disk" refers to a closed disk, or to any topological space homeomorphic to the closed disk. So, competing conventions in different realms of mathematics perhaps explains the ambiguities you are encountering. There's probably quite a few mathematicians with solid training (and even substantial contributions) in both geometric topology and complex analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may mean either the open or the closed disk, depending on the author and the context.  There isn't a universal standard.

I disagree with Wikipedia's categorical claim that "open" is *always* the default, though I would say that *more often than not*, "disk" by itself means "open disk".  Especially in complex analysis.

In the linked question, the use of the word "inside" seems to hint that the open disk is intended, though this is not necessarily definitive.  Anyway, for that question the zeros are in fact inside the *open* unit disk, although the current answers only show they're in the closed disk.

To see why, suppose $P(z) = 0$ and $|z|=1$.  As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/286825/822), we have
$$n = |n z^n| = |1 + z + \dots + z^{n-1}| \le |1+z| + |z|^2 + \dots + |z|^{n-1} = |1+z| + (n-2)$$
using the triangle inequality.
Rearranging, we must have $|1+z| \ge 2$.  This is only possible if $z=1$, and clearly $P(1) \ne 0$, so this is a contradiction.